# Android : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find "libtiff.so"

Tags: android, tiff, libtiff

I want to open **Tiff** files but native image viewer is unable to open tiff files. So i downloaded project from the following path.
[TiffonAndroid](https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/source/clones)

I have taken all the src, res files from that project and added them to my project. While running i am getting this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tiffviewer-2/base.apk"], 
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtiff.so".
```

`libtiff.so` is c++ based library project. How to resolve the above issue can we add c++based projects to Our general android project?

Answer (score 0):

This happened when your APK didn't include the native library inside it. Yes, you can add native support for you current Android project. If you use Eclipse as your IDE, right mouse click on your project, `Android Tool` -> `Add Native Support...`. For more information, take a look at the [official document](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use JNI, and copy a .so file，you must put the class which contains the native methods in the right package (defined in .so) and use the same name which is defined in .so.

```
package site.zhuzijian.jnitest;
public class NdkJniUtils {
public static native String getLanguageString(String name);

public static native String[] cryptRequest(String uuid, String time, String[] contents);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("jnitest");
}}
```

and this .h file

```
#include <jni.h>
#ifndef _Included_site_zhuzijian_jnitest_NdkJniUtils
#define _Included_site_zhuzijian_jnitest_NdkJniUtils
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_site_zhuzijian_jnitest_NdkJniUtils_getLanguageString
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_site_zhuzijian_jnitest_NdkJniUtils_cryptRequest
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring, jobjectArray);

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  #endif`
```

You may not see this .h file because it is compiled in .so file.
As you see, the method in .h file contain the package name. It must match the package of NdkJniUtils